# Apple Clang C++ Compiler and OpenMP result in "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang, openmp

I am trying to compile [this](https://github.com/oofem/oofem) software with OpenMP cmake option ON.
I have installed OpenMP from Homebrew using `brew install libomp`.

I use environmental variables `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib` and `CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include` to include paths of OpenMP.

Even though the compilation is successful at the linking libraries stage I encounter the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> ...
> ...
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think the problem should be simple and the path of the OpenMP library/lib is not recognized. I'd appreciate if someone could give me some hint on how to resolve this issue..

---

**This is the full compilation log:**

```
====================[ Build | oofem | Release_OMP ]=============================
[  5%] Built target fm
[ 12%] Built target tm
[ 47%] Built target core
[ 98%] Built target sm
[ 98%] Built target sm
[100%] Linking CXX shared library liboofem.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_barrier", referenced from:
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::init(bool) in octreelocalizer.C.o
  "___kmpc_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..35 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..37 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..62 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..66 in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleExtrapolatedForces(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..35 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..37 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..62 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..66 in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleExtrapolatedForces(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_single", referenced from:
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::init(bool) in octreelocalizer.C.o
  "___kmpc_for_static_fini", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..34 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..35 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..37 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..62 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..64 in engngm.C.o
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..34 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..35 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..37 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..62 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..66 in engngm.C.o
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_8", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..64 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..67 in engngm.C.o
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVectorFromDofManagers(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVectorFromBC(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVectorFromElements(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::MatrixAssembler const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::MatrixAssembler const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::TransportGradientDirichlet::computeTangent(oofem::FloatMatrix&, oofem::TimeStep*) in transportgradientdirichlet.C.o
      ...
  "___kmpc_global_thread_num", referenced from:
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::init(bool) in octreelocalizer.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleExtrapolatedForces(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assemblePrescribedExtrapolatedForces(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
  "___kmpc_single", referenced from:
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::init(bool) in octreelocalizer.C.o
  "_omp_init_lock", referenced from:
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::OctreeSpatialLocalizer(oofem::Domain*) in octreelocalizer.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVectorFromBC(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::MatrixAssembler const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::MatrixAssembler const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*) in engngm.C.o
      oofem::EngngModel::assembleVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::VectorAssembler const&, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::Domain*, oofem::FloatArray*) in engngm.C.o
  "_omp_set_lock", referenced from:
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::giveInternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::FloatArray*, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::giveExternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, double, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::PrescribedMean::giveInternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::FloatArray*, void*) in prescribedmean.C.o
      oofem::PrescribedMean::giveExternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, void*) in prescribedmean.C.o
      oofem::PrescribedMean::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, double, void*) in prescribedmean.C.o
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::initElementIPDataStructure() in octreelocalizer.C.o
      ...
  "_omp_unset_lock", referenced from:
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::giveInternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::FloatArray*, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::giveExternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::WeakPeriodicBoundaryCondition::assemble(oofem::SparseMtrx&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, double, void*) in weakperiodicbc.C.o
      oofem::PrescribedMean::giveInternalForcesVector(oofem::FloatArray&, oofem::TimeStep*, oofem::CharType, oofem::ValueModeType, oofem::UnknownNumberingScheme const&, oofem::FloatArray*, void*) in prescribedmean.C.o
      oofem::OctreeSpatialLocalizer::initElementIPDataStructure() in octreelocalizer.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..34 in engngm.C.o
      _.omp_outlined..64 in engngm.C.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [liboofem.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/liboofem.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/oofem.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [oofem] Error 2
```

Comment: With the current error message is is unclear which symbols are not found and in which files. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**. Also, please show output of `cmake` about finding/not finding OpenMP.

Comment: The version of OpenMP of your compiler may not match with the one of the runtime. Alternatively the OpenMP flags are maybe missing from the linker. These undefined symbols should be in the LLVM/Intel OpenMP runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but how do I know LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib is even working? What if the linker is not even looking in the OpenMP directory that I have provided?